# How do I separate elements containing specific variables into separate lists?

Tags: c#

I have a file filled with data separated by line. I need to organize the data based on a specific variable found in each line in text format. I want to take the data and split it into three different files based on this variable.

Here's an example of the data I have:

```
BLUS30755;007 GoldenEye: Reloaded - Emilio Largo;DLC;US;url;;;;Anonymous
BLUS30755;007 GoldenEye: Reloaded - Pussy Galore;DLC;US;;;;;Anonymous
NPJW90016;100 Man Ton no BaraBara - PS3 Wallpaper #01;Wallpaper;JP;;;;;Slimshady451
NPJW90016;100 Man Ton no BaraBara - PSP Wallpaper #01;Wallpaper;JP;;;;;Slimshady451
NPUZ00262;1000 Tiny Claws;Mini;US;;;;;Anonymous
NPEB00026;1942: Joint Strike;PSN;EU;;;;;shinobi
```

The variable I'm trying to separate by is region code. (US, EU, JP)

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile.

Comment: This is not a question about the Visual Studio application. Please do not use the `[visual-studio]` tag for such questions as this. Also, please include a little more code. It's not clear why each item would be written to all directories, since clearly `region` can only be one value at a time.

Comment: use `yourstring.split(';')` to an array, that should solve ur problem

Comment: You should read [ask]. We don't have enough information to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

You may look at [String.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8) to do what you want.

If what you want is to retrieve the region, you can do something like this, where you split your line by ';' then check the 4th element:

```
string test = "NPEB00026;1942: Joint Strike;PSN;EU;;;;;shinobi";

        switch (test.Split(';')[3])
        {
            case "EU":
                // Here put your code to sort EU
                break;
            case "US":
                // Here put your code to sort US
                break;
            case "JP":
                // Here put your code to sort JP
                break;
            default:
                // Here put your code to sort others
                break;
        }
```

Comment: What I wanted to do is to use the region to filter the entire string based on the region.

Comment: It is what I do. test.Split(';') create an array with each element between ';' as values. The 4th element(number [3] for an array, because it starts at 0) is use in the switch. If the text is "JP", the code is gonna go in the case "JP". So you can write the code to sort your string in each case.